# Getting contact between nodes from different hierarchy

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

How do you get contact between nodes from different hierarchy in the node tree, say a node in the scene (ball) and a child node (wall) of another node.

I have tried to build a plate with 4 walls which are child node of the plate. then I added a ball to the plate node (I also tried to let the ball be in the scene) and let it move. after defining the physics body, still I can't get a contact.

Here is my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let plate = SKSpriteNode ()
    let wall1 = SKSpriteNode ()
    let wall2 = SKSpriteNode ()
    let wall3 = SKSpriteNode ()
    let wall4 = SKSpriteNode ()
    var ball = SKShapeNode ()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.backgroundColor = .white


    plate.size = CGSize (width: self.size.width * 0.6 , height: self.size.width * 0.6)
    plate.position = CGPoint (x: self.size.width / 2 , y: self.size.height / 2 )
    plate.color = .orange
    plate.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(plate)

    plate.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: plate.frame)
    plate.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    plate.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    plate.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    plate.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    plate.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    plate.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    plate.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0


    wall1.size = CGSize (width: plate.size.width * 0.1, height: plate.size.height)
    wall1.position = CGPoint (x: plate.size.width / 2, y: 0 )
    wall1.color = .gray
    wall1.zPosition = 2
    plate.addChild(wall1)

    wall1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: wall1.frame)


    wall2.size = CGSize (width: plate.size.width * 0.1, height: plate.size.height)
    wall2.position = CGPoint (x: 0, y: plate.size.height / 2 )
    wall2.zRotation = plate.zRotation + .pi/2
    wall2.color = .yellow
    wall2.zPosition = 2
    plate.addChild(wall2)

    wall2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: wall2.frame)

    wall3.size = CGSize (width: plate.size.width * 0.1, height: plate.size.height)
    wall3.position = CGPoint (x: -plate.size.width / 2, y: 0 )
    wall3.color = .cyan
    wall3.zPosition = 2
    plate.addChild(wall3)

    wall3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: wall3.frame)

    wall4.size = CGSize (width: plate.size.width * 0.1, height: plate.size.height)
    wall4.position = CGPoint (x: 0, y: -plate.size.height / 2 )
    wall4.zRotation = plate.zRotation + .pi/2
    wall4.color = .magenta
    wall4.zPosition = 2
    plate.addChild(wall4)

    wall4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: wall4.frame)
    wall4.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    wall4.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    wall4.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    wall4.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    wall4.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    wall4.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    wall4.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    ball = SKShapeNode (circleOfRadius: 10)
    ball.strokeColor = .black
    ball.lineWidth = 2
    ball.fillColor = .blue
    ball.position = CGPoint (x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    ball.zPosition = 2
    plate.addChild(ball)

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: 10)
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1





}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    plate.zRotation -= .pi/36
}}
```

I can't even have contact between my ball and the borders of the plate itself.

Thanks

Comment: Your plate and walls have `category` and `contactTest` bit masks of 0, so they are not going to collide or generate contacts with anything.

Comment: That was the case, thanks. But still I get the actual contact in a different place. I mean the place of the wall is somewhere and the ball is hitting it further down in the empty space of the scene for instance. How does sprite kit detect position of nodes that are not direct child of the scene and how we can handle it?

Comment: A node’s child or parent relationships have no bearing on collisions or contact detection. How do you know that “the ball is hitting it ... in the empty space of the scene”?

Comment: This is what happens in the simulator. I think the calculation of the physics body position is done according to the scene, while the sprite positions are coordinated according to their paret. It really gets complicated. Let me ask in another way. I make a sprite node (plate) and let a ball move or fall inside it. Although I have define it's physics body as (edgeLoopFrom plate.frame) th ball doesn't stop by the edge. What's wrong?

Comment: If you have weird behaviour in the simulator, then try it on a real device. contact Detections, even with a simple game, is erratic on my 2015 12" Macbook, much better on my 2011 MBP and flawless on even an iPhone 5.

Comment: Really? That much difference can they make? I'll try it.